# Recommended Duplex setting for physical NIC when doing Virtualization

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware-esxi, hyper-v

What is the recommended Duplex setting for a physical network adapter when using virtualization? Let's assume that the physical network switch ports are configured for auto negotiation and support speeds up to 1GB. How should I set the duplex settings on the physical adapter and the duplex settings on the VM virtual adapters?

Or it doesn't matter -> meaning the virtual nics can do whatever the physical nic supports, host settings are ignored?

Or it does matter you need to set the duplex settings to....for maximum performance?

Comment: It doesn't matter. You normally shouldn't be messing with any of this. Are you having an actual problem? If so, you should ask about that.

Comment: You shouldn't need to change the settings of the vNIC at all. I've never seen or read of anyone doing this or having any reason to do this. `Or it does matter you need to set the duplex settings to....for maximum performance?` - That's an overly broad, overly simplistic, and loaded question. Define what "maximum performance" means to you in the context of your question.

Comment: @ joeqwerty We have an application that hiccups when the nic duplex settings are set to auto. We have virtualized the server and we are afraid we might see performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should let the hypervisor handle all of this.  The hypervisor assumes it has full control of the host's resources and allocates them to your VMs.  You should only make changes if you're seeing some kind of issue.

Depending on the hypervisor, the virtual NICs will generally have the same capabilities as the physical NIC, although you might miss some brand specific features.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you shouldn't ever set a NIC to manual speed or duplex unless you absolutely have to. Manual NIC speed and duplex settings deactivate autonegotiation and can lead to unexpected results.

On gigabit upwards, autoneg is mandatory. Forcing a manual speed downgrades to 100 or 10 Mbit/s. Forcing full duplex deactivates autoneg and makes the other side fall back to half(!) duplex - the duplex mismatch creates severe problems.

General rule: **always leave autonegotiation activated**